# how to add search bar under the navigation title

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

[image: please see my screen shot i need this][image: this is the previous output before adding image]I need the search bar under the navigation title how to do that programmatically or via story board.

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,30, 250,44)];
searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
UIBarButtonItem *searchBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:searchBar];
searchBarItem.tag = 123;
searchBarItem.customView.hidden = YES;
searchBarItem.customView.alpha = 0.0f;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = searchBarItem;
self.navigationItem.title = @"locations";
```

Comment: can you show some screen shot how do u need

Comment: whats issue you face ? tell us with some Screen

Comment: you need this inside the naivation bar or bottom of navigation bar

Comment: inside the navigation controller. it contains navigation title and searchbar

Comment: but the problem i add the navaigation title the search bar hidded and also search bar is added to navigation title  the navigation title is hidded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added the search bar as `UIBarButtonItem`, thats why it is not visible.

If you want to display the search bar in place of the title view of navigation bar the use this code

**Code to show navigation bar in place of Title of Navigation :**

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]init];
searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar;
```

Output :

[image]

**Code to show navigation bar below the Navigation bar:**

```
UISearchBar *searchBar1 = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 64)];
searchBar1.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
searchBar1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
searchBar1.placeholder = @"Search";
[self.view addSubview:searchBar1];
```

UPDATE :

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
searchBar1.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;

UISearchBar *searchBar1 = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 64)];
searchBar1.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
searchBar1.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
searchBar1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
searchBar1.placeholder = @"Search";
[self.view addSubview:searchBar1];

[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setDefaultTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];
```

Output :

[image]

Updated output

**To customize the textField :**

```
UISearchBar *searchBar1 = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 64)];
searchBar1.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
searchBar1.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
searchBar1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
searchBar1.placeholder = @"Search";
[self.view addSubview:searchBar1];

[searchBar1 setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"text-input.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The image I have used is of height 30 pixel like the search bar's text field.

here is the image :

[image]

And output :

[image]
Hope it helps ...

Happy coding ...

[image: updated output]

Comment: is works good. but i need to set the background color for navigation controller and searchbar how to do that.

Comment: You can use this code to make the navigation bar to look Red :

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];

Comment: this code changes the color of navigation controller only. but i need to set the search inside the navigation controller and also under the title not in view.

Comment: i mean subview is not a view.

Comment: I did not get your point, lets talk with an example, there is navigation bar, search bar and main view (main view means the view apart from navigation area). Now your requirement is to make the navigation bar as red color , search bar as red color and main view as red color ? And tell me which one is your requirement, my first answer or second one ?

Comment: i need navigation bar as red color and  search bar as red color

Comment: Ok then use the search bar style property like this :      
                    

    searchBar1.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;

Then the back ground color given will be shown as the search bar background color . Let me know if it works ..

Comment: it changes the color of searchbar only.

Comment: You need to set the navigation color by :     self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];

And searchbar color by it style . So you need to combine both code to make the color of navigation bar and search bar as same color by setting same color.

Comment: it similarly meet my output. but i need inside the searchbar i mean text search area as a white color thats all.

Comment: the code changes the color of all screens navigation color but i need particular screen navigation color only.

Comment: can you please tell how to add screen shot. for your reference.

Comment: As the navigation controller is one, so changing in one screen, changes for all. So the solution is set the color as clear color in other screen except the screen. Remember to put the code for setting color in "viewWillAppear"

Comment: how to set the white color for text search area.

Comment: add this code :     [[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setDefaultTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];

Comment: Up vote the answer, to confirm as the answer you need.

Comment: sorry the color of textfield not changed

Comment: plz tell how change the input field of search bar

Comment: Check my updated answer, i have shown the screen shot it is working. Are you using the same way like i did. Also let me know the iOS version you are using ..?

Comment: i dont want text color i need text field color as a white

Comment: Use image for that , take a input filed image with white color and set it in place of "text-input.png":

    [searchBar1 setSearchFieldBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"text-input.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: please tell how to add screen shot.

Comment: You can add image in your question, not in comment. Edit your question, you will see the gallery logo next to curly brace "{}", click that, then drag your image into that image pop up area, then post

Comment: It should work, show your code, I don't have the text field image of accurate dimension, or else i could have shown you the screen shot.

Comment: Check out my latest edit, with screen shot. How could you say it does not work ???

Comment: please see my screen shot and answer for that. i dont know how to explain that.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use textbox as search bar, it is working fine in my app,

Go to `StoryBoard` and do the following changes

From Object `Library--> type view` and drag to `storyboard` and paste below the Navigation bar.

Add the textbox to the view and assign the outlets and delegates.

now go to `viewcontroller.m` and paste the following code

```html
-(void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField
{
    searchTextString=textField.text;
    [self updateSearchArray:searchTextString];
}


-(void)updateSearchArray:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if(searchText.length==0)
    {
        isFilter=NO;
    }
    else
    {
        isFilter=YES;
        searchArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    
        for(NSString *string in responceArray)
        {
            NSRange stringRange = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",string]
                               rangeOfString:searchtext.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        
            if (stringRange.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [searchArray addObject:string];
            }
        }
        [jobsTable reloadData];
     }
}
```

Now it will work fine..